# C# Windows7 open Scanner Options from System Control

Tags: c#

I wrote an Program which allows the User to put in Recipes in the Scanner, which have on the Background labeled an Barcode. It reads and outputs the Barcodes from this Scanned Images.

Now my Question is actually to get Access to the Scanner I made an Shortcut from the Scanner out of the Devices and Printer and put that Shortcut in my Program folder. To open it Up in my Programm I used this Code:

Process.Start(@"explorer.exe", "scan.lnk");

Sometimes It opens an Window of the Properties from the Shortcut instead of the Scanner Window where I can Start the Scanning Process.

Is there any Solution so that my Program automatically uses the Basic Scanner.

MFG Pascal

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: A file name is not a valid command line argument to Explorer.exe. Its still not clear what your question is. You want to know "Is there any Solution so that my Program automatically uses the Basic Scanner" but it's not clear what you mean by "use" or "the Basic Scanner."